# Quick lightweight Shopping Cart with PayPal integration

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart, cart

I have built a couple of Shoppping Carts with Magento recently but I feel it is far too bulky for the shop I will be building next. I will be building a shop that sells only 4 DVDs for a seasonal promotion.

Can anyone recommend a PHP Shopping Cart / Script with Back-end functionality that can be quickly built. What would you use in similar situation?

Thanks,

gemmes

Comment: Please add which of those found in the various http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=shopping+cart+php results you already ruled out.

Comment: Magento, ZenCart, OSCommerce, PrestaShop. All nice carts that do almost everything. I want a tiny Paypal only cart in order to sell 4 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found SimpleCartJS is pretty close to what I needed. I would still prefer a PHP cart with a small admin interface for keep track of orders, items, etc.